# Is it possible to validate an AzureAd token by http request?

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-msal

I have been tasked with validating AzureAd tokens in an existing API without adding additional dependencies to the project.  Is it possible to validate a token by making an http request to azure and passing along the token?

I know that my test configuration that leverages the `Microsoft.Identity.Web` package (which I am asked to avoid for the final result), in additional to the ClientId, TenantId, and scopes has the Instance as https://login.microsoftonline.com/, so I assume an underlying http call is being made.

Is there any documentation to show how I could manually build such an http request to validate the token that way?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no endpoint that does that.

What happens under the hood:

1. You provide the library the `Authority`, for example `https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/v2.0`
2. The library (basic JWT/OpenID Connect authentication provider or Microsoft.Identity.Web) constructs the metadata URL by adding `/.well-known/openid-configuration` to the end: https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration
3. The metadata URL is loaded at startup. It contains another URL in the `jwks_uri` property of the JSON, for example: https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/discovery/v2.0/keys
4. This URL is then also loaded to get the public signing keys
5. Using the signing keys, the library can verify the token signature is valid and the token has not been modified. It does this by looking at the `kid` (key id) in the token header part and finds the matching key from the keys it loaded. Then it's a matter of applying asymmetric cryptography stuff.
6. It then checks the issuer (`iss`), validity start time (`iat`), expiry time (`exp`) + potentially some other things
7. You will have provided the library at least with a valid audience in addition to the authority. It also checks that the audience (`aud`) matches this.

So the token validation only requires the OpenID Connect metadata + the public signing keys for the key pairs that Azure AD might use to sign tokens.
After these are loaded, the app does not need a connection to Azure AD to validate tokens.
Usually libraries do reload the metadata and signing keys once in a while, since keys can change at times, though quite rarely.

Comment: So, if done manually, it would be necessary to pull down the metadata and signing keys and then manually implement all the cryptography stuff?  I just want to make sure there are no built in packages that come with .NET 6 Core by default that facilitate this, to where an additional 3rd party package would be avoidable.

Comment: In ASP.NET Core, you would typically use the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer` library. In other cases I would use the `Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.OpenIdConnect` library combined with `System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt` library. You really don't want to be writing crypto code by hand as it is quite easy to make mistakes that aren't obvious.

Comment: Okay last follow-up:  I am currently using the Microsoft.Identity.Web package, which includes the JwtBearer library.  It seems to make the implementation very simple overall.  As an Azure professional, if project dependencies weren't an issue, would you prefer the Identity.Web package, or a slightly more manual approach with the JwtBearer package?

Comment: If all you are doing is validating the token, the JwtBearer library does that quite easily. At minimum you define the valid audience + authority to it and it's done. You do still need to authorize the request but that you need to do anyway. Identity.Web adds some other stuff like fetching tokens to other services based on the token you received and such. If you need that, then it can be a good option.